# Define interface member only when generic parameter matches pattern

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add TypeScript typings to [my (non-TypeScript) library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/iterjs). I have an interface type `Iter<T>` that is generic on a user-defined type, and defines several methods, which are all working great except for `flatten`:

```
interface Iter<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    map<U>(transform: Transform<T, U>): Iter<U>;
    filter(predicate: Predicate<T>): Iter<T>;
    ...
    flatten(): Iter<any>; // ?
}
```

The semantics of `flatten` are that it operates on some iter of type `Iter<Iterable<U>>` and flattens them into an `Iter<U>`. In .NET terms, it would be the same as `SelectMany(x => x)`; in Python terms, it's like itertools' `chain`.

The question is: is there any way to have a more specific return type for `flatten`? Or, equivalently, is there a way to only define a method on an interface when the interface's generic parameter matches some constraint?

Something like (hypothetical syntax):

```
interface Iter<T> extends Iterable<T> {
  ...
  flatten<U>(): Iter<U> when T : Iterable<U>;
}
```

or

```
interface Iter<Iterable<U>> extends Iter<T> {
  flatten(): Iter<U>;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `T` is not `Iterable`?

Comment: It's iterated with `yield *`, which I'm pretty sure would raise a `TypeError` in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Define interface member only when generic parameter matches pattern

No. The member will exist at all times.

Comment: Yes, I looked into lodash's typings for the chained version of `flatten`, and they just punt by returning `LodashArrayWrapper<any>` (analogous to my `Iter<any>`). So I come to the conclusion that TypeScript's type definitions are just not advanced enough to represent this scenario.